# Referring local element of different namespace in another xsd?

Tags: xsd

Requirement is such that I want only some elements defined in xsd's to be accessible as root elements.
So, for that the approach is to make all the other elements local by declaring complex types and referring them.

But, if tho**se non-accessible or local elements are required in another xsd definition, in other words**, they can be child elements of the elements belonging to some other namespace defined in a different xsd.

How to achieve this kind of schema definition?

For e.g In the following 
say I only want **A:root and custom:root** to be valid roots not **inner:A**, so I declared innerA under the root element and referred the type, while A:innerA can come under the  element?

I cannot define innerA in B.xsd, bcz **it will make the innerA to be in B.xsd's targetnamespace i.e custom namespace**.

For e.g.

A.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://www.abc.com/custom"
    xmlns:A="http://www.abc.com/A" 
    xmlns:custom="http://www.abc.com/custom">
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.abc.com/custom"
        schemaLocation="B.xsd"/>

<xsd:complexType name="innerType">
   <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="abc" type="xs:string"/>
   </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:element name="root">
        <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
            <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:element ref="custom:root">
                 <xsd:element name="innerA" type="A:innerType"/>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

B.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://www.abc.com/custom"
    xmlns:A="http://www.abc.com/A" 
    xmlns:custom="http://www.abc.com/custom">
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.abc.com/A"
        schemaLocation="A.xsd"/>
    <xsd:element name="root">
        <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="A:innerA"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:element>
```

**The Fourth last line in above B.xsd causes error. How can I refer the innerA element. Any suggetions?**

XML

```
 <A:root xmlns:A="http://www.abc.com/a" xmlns:custom="http://www.abc.com/custom"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation=""http://www.abc.com/a "http://www.abc.com/a/A.xsd">
    <custom:root>
       <A:innerA>
          <A:abc>
       </A:innerA>
    </custom:root>
    </A:hello>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, you cannot reference an element declared locally (think private in Java or C#).If it's global, then it can be a root element in a document. The only way to prevent a global to be a root element would be to implement an extension in your validation program that would check what element is at the root. You could use appinfo if you want to make your approach generic.

Let's assume you're using .NET. Before using the XML you could check the qualified name of the document element to see if it is in the allowed list. You could configure this list in a separate configuration file, or you could use the XSD itself. To validate XML, you have to compile the XSD in an XmlSchemaSet anyway; so if you use some markup in the appinfo, then you could visit all the global elements, check for that markup, and when found, add that element's qualified name to the list I was referring above.

If Java, you could do something similar.

If you're dealing with a language that doesn't support a schema object model, then you could process the XSDs as XML files. The problem with this is that it gets complicated, as you would have to traverse the includes/imports, basically you would end up dealing with resolving external references yourself.

One thing you have to keep in mind is that if you end up using XSDs that are not yours, yet those XSD use global elements, there's nothing you can do with appinfo. You stick with the preconfigured list.

There is no link, since this is my own idea to your problem. If instead you were looking for documentation on appinfo, then try [this one](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cAnnotations).

Comment: hmm...Can you provide details on how can i write an extension to validation? Appinfo? Can you provide some link to your answer?

Comment: thanks for the answer, I am using java, but I do not want to do this handling in java. Then can it be possible?Constraints are such that, I only have to do this validation in xsd